# Bx-slider not infinite

Tags: javascript, jquery, zend-framework2, bxslider

I bought a theme from a website, and i have some problems with bxslider...when on the last slide, it does not show next slides until the last slide gets to the front of the slider, which does not look good. you can see the preview [HERE](http://toprestaurantsoffers.com). and the bought theme [HERE](http://uouapps.com/portfolio/top10/bar/?theme=uouapps)

here is the code that generates the slides:

```
 <ul class="top_video_slider">
        <?=$this->topRestaurants(45.8, 23.0);?>
 </ul>
```

`$this->topRestaurants()` returns the `$string` generated like so:

```
 foreach($topRest as $restaurant) {
     $slug = $service->create($restaurant['name'], false) . '-' . $restaurant['id'];
     $photos = explode(',', $restaurant['images']);
     $string .= '<li>
         <div class="video_holder">
     <a href="/restaurant/'.$slug.'"><img src="/uploads/'.$photos[0].'" alt="image"></a> 
         </div>
     </li>';
   }
```

the jquery for it looks like this:

```
$('.top_video_slider').bxSlider({
    slideMargin: 10, useCSS: false,
    pager: true, auto: true, autoHover:true,
    onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
    $(".top_video_slider").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
```

can you please please help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it using the "maxSlides" option from bxslider...i modified it to be less than the total of slides.

the jquery looks like so:

```
$('.top_video_slider').bxSlider({
    slideMargin: 10, useCSS: false,
    pager: false, auto: true, autoHover:true, infiniteLoop: true, maxSlides: 8,
    onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
    $(".top_video_slider").css("visibility", "visible");
}});
```

All the slides show now, but there is no space next to the last one